# Improve swap image code

Tags: android

Is there a way to make this code simpler? It seems repeating 
The code is for two ImageViews that swap and change skin onClick, changing some labels at the same time.
Thanks!

```
public void imgChangeUnit(View v) { 
    TextView lbl_unT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.unT);
    TextView lbl_unOD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.unOD);
    TextView lbl_unID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.unID);
    TextView lbl_unit_res = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_unit_res);
    ImageView myImg_mm = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgMetric);
     ImageView myImg_in = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgImperial);

if (isUnit(lbl_unit_res)) {
    lbl_unT.setText("inch");
    lbl_unOD.setText("inch");
    lbl_unID.setText("inch");
    lbl_unit_res.setText("Feet");               

    myImg_in.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_but_imperial_on));
    myImg_mm.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_but_metric_off));   

    } else {
    lbl_unT.setText("mm");
    lbl_unOD.setText("mm");
    lbl_unID.setText("mm");
    lbl_unit_res.setText("Meters"); 

    myImg_mm.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_but_metric_on));
    myImg_in.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_but_imperial_off));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This already looks a bit better.
At least you don´t have variable repetition any more.

You might want to create method like setToImperial() and setToMetric(), that would know what to get and set. 
It would even be better.

Also, note that you shouldn´t hardcode Strings in android, but use the [string resources file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

```
public void imgChangeUnit(View v) {

    TextView lbl_unT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.unT);
    TextView lbl_unOD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.unOD);
    TextView lbl_unID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.unID);
    TextView lbl_unit_res = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_unit_res);
    ImageView myImg_mm = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgMetric);
    ImageView myImg_in = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgImperial);

    String unit;
    String unit2;
    Drawable d1;
    Drawable d2;
    if (isUnit(lbl_unit_res)) {
        unit = "inch";
        unit2 = "Feet";

        d1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_but_imperial_on);
        d2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_but_metric_off);

    } 
    else {
        unit = "mm";
        unit2 = "Meters";

        d1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_but_metric_on);
        d2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_but_imperial_off);
    }


    lbl_unT.setText(unit);
    lbl_unOD.setText(unit);
    lbl_unID.setText(unit);
    lbl_unit_res.setText(unit2);     

    myImg_mm.setImageDrawable(d1);
    myImg_in.setImageDrawable(d2);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that isUnit(lbl_unit_res) is a Boolean returned True when is "metric", so in my code if it's "Metric" then the function imgChangeUnit() turns all into "Imperial".

Comment: Thanks jlengrand, I suppose the last two rows should end like "...getDrawable(R.drawable.d1)" and "...(R.drawable.d2)", right?

Comment: My bad, it was a copy paste error. The code should be ok now.